# ShareLatex CVPR template not compiling tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, sharelatex

I have never worked with tikz before. The question is very basic. In the CVPR ShareLatex [Template](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/computer-vision-and-pattern-recognition-(cvpr)), when I add just `\usepackage{tikz}`, there is compile error. The lines of error are different as well. I have tried in vain, changing the order of the `\usepackage` commands. Any suggestions on the same? The link for the template is attached!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That template looks pretty horribly broken. The `eso-pic.sty` file isn't actually the real file. It's hacked to `\input{cvpr_eso.sty}` rather than `\RequirePackage{atbeginshi}` at least. But `cvpr_eso.sty` appears to actually be `everyshi`.

To fix it, delete `cvpr_eso.sty` and `eso-pic.sty`. Now everything should compile with `\usepackage{tikz}`.

Other bad things about that template:

- The `epsfig` package should not be used; `graphicx` replaces it.
- The `times` package should probably not be used. Use `mathptmx` instead.